# How to force an Angular Component to load up external script in its template

Tags: javascript, angular

I am a newbie working on a project. Some components in my app need external (third-party) scripts for some features to work properly, and all I just need to do is include, locally or via a CDN, the script via the  tag in the HTML templates of the components. I've read so many questions on this platform and none of them has particularly addressed my use case:

I just want to add an external script tag like this: `<script src="./assets/vendor/bla-bla-bla.min.js"></script>` to my Component's template, and force Angular to be aware of the script and load them dynamically when ever I route to my Component. That's all!

Angular CLI 13.0.4,
npm 8.19.2,
node 18.12.1

Comment: another way is just to add the script tag in component.html file

Answer (score 0):

here you can use this logic :

**apiVariableNameHere** is variable name or api from your url that needs to be called.

```js
declare let apiVariableNameHere: any;

@Component({
  selector: "app-root",
  templateUrl: "./app.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./app.component.css"]
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(
    private renderer: Renderer2,
  ) { }
 
  ngOnInit() {
  this.loadScript(yourUrl);
  }
  
   public loadScript(url) {
        let node = document.createElement('script');
        node.src = url;
        node.type = 'text/javascript';
        node.async = true;
        node.charset = 'utf-8';
        document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(node);
    }
}
```